# Android Jetpack Compose and Viewmodels - Best practices when state hoisting, deriving state, and avoiding extra recompositions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have previously created Android apps using Java and Fragments. I am making a new app and am transitioning to Jetpack Compose and the MVVM style of organizing apps. As I have started programming my app, I have some questions about fundamental architecture design of apps using these principles in the Jetpack Compose framework. I have done a lot of research and tutorials on state hoisting, recomposition, etc... Here is my full minimum code example:

`TestState.k`:

```
package com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme

data class TestState(
    val variable1: Boolean = false
)

data class TestState2(
    val variable2: Boolean = false
)
```

`TestViewModel.k`:

```
package com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import timber.log.Timber

class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(TestState())
    private val _uiState2 = MutableStateFlow(TestState2())
    val uiState: StateFlow<TestState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    val uiState2: StateFlow<TestState2> = _uiState2.asStateFlow()

    fun function1(newState: Boolean){
        Timber.v("ViewModel sees that switch is $newState")
        _uiState.update { currentState ->
            currentState.copy(
                variable1 = newState
            )
        }
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.testdemonstration

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme.TestDemonstrationTheme
import com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme.TestViewModel
import timber.log.Timber

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val testViewModel by viewModels<TestViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val uiState by testViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
            val uiState2 by testViewModel.uiState2.collectAsState()
            TestDemonstrationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    FirstStage(passedViewModel = testViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstStage(passedViewModel: TestViewModel) {
    val uiState by passedViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val uiState2 by passedViewModel.uiState2.collectAsState()
    if(uiState2.variable2){
        Timber.v("Do something when variable2 is true")
    } else {
        Timber.v("Do something when variable2 is false")
    }
    Buttons(variable1 = uiState.variable1, passedFunction = {passedViewModel.function1(it)})
}

@Composable
fun Buttons(variable1: Boolean, passedFunction: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Row() {
        Text(text = "Test app")
        Switch(
            checked = variable1,
            onCheckedChange = passedFunction
        )
    }
}
```

Now, when I toggle the switch, in my `logcat` I see:

```
V  ViewModel sees that switch is true
V  Do something when variable2 is false
```

Toggle back again:

```
V  ViewModel sees that switch is false
V  Do something when variable2 is false
```

My simple attempt to change `variable1` with a switch is resulting in `FirstStage` getting recomposed when I don't want it to and doing the light logic based on `variable2`. This seems like an inefficiency that would grow with the scope of the app.

I understand that one way is to not have the Switch in the same Composable chain as `FirstStage`. However, my architecture is such that the switch needs to be a child Composable of `FirstStage`. One naive fix I tried was:

```
package com.example.testdemonstration

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Switch
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme.TestDemonstrationTheme
import com.example.testdemonstration.ui.theme.TestViewModel
import timber.log.Timber

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val testViewModel by viewModels<TestViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val uiState by testViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
            val uiState2 by testViewModel.uiState2.collectAsState()
            TestDemonstrationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    FirstStage(variable1 = uiState.variable1, variable2 = uiState2.variable2,
                        passedFunction = {testViewModel.function1(it)})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstStage(variable1: Boolean, variable2: Boolean, passedFunction: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    if(variable2){
        Timber.v("Do something when variable2 is true")
    } else {
        Timber.v("Do something when variable2 is false")
    }
    Buttons(variable1 = variable1, passedFunction = passedFunction)
}

@Composable
fun Buttons(variable1: Boolean, passedFunction: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Row() {
        Text(text = "Test app")
        Switch(
            checked = variable1,
            onCheckedChange = passedFunction
        )
    }
}
```

And when toggling on:

```
V  ViewModel sees that switch is true
V  Do something when variable2 is false
```

and off:

```
V  ViewModel sees that switch is false
V  Do something when variable2 is false
```

I still seem to have the same unnecessary recomposition. So is there no way to nest my Composables like this without triggering extraneous recompositions? Or is there some elegant way to avoid this?

I have my example structured like this because I want my app to have a nested Composable switch that begins operations that require permissions. The app will need to ask users for permissions. I want the user's rejection or acceptance of the permissions to be a state in the ViewModel so that other elements of the UI could adapt based on the permissions given. My understanding was that for a Single Activity app, the top MainActivity level of the app should be the one that calls the activity that asks the user for permissions and receives the feedback. Therefore, my MainActivity level needs to have access to the ViewModel and states.

It's very possible that I am architecting this inefficiently, if so, please recommend a better architecture or where I can read about this. I didn't see anything in Android's docs or [tutorials](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-unscramble/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/example/unscramble/ui/GameScreen.kt).

Even if I do change the architecture with regards to permissions, the fundamental question remains - dealing with how to have all these nested Composables use different states of the same ViewModel, and not trigger unnecessary recompositions.